# Mac OS X slow connections - mdns 4-5 seconds - bonjour slow

Tags: php, macos, active-directory, ldap, domaincontroller

I'm finally at my wits end. I've been Googling this issue for a week now. I've tried troubleshooting my Mac (10.12 Sierra) and my domain controllers (Windows Server 2016) and I am no closer to solving my issue.

My issue is that when using PHP's [ldap_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php) function, it takes about 5 seconds before I get a response. Things just sort of hang for 5 seconds then I get a successful connection. The exact command to replicate this (assuming my DC has an IP address of `192.168.2.5`):

`$ldap = ldap_connect('ldap://192.168.2.5:389');`

I'm not using SSL or TLS. It's just a simple plaintext connection to a DC with its firewall completely turned off. I ended up installing Wireshark on my DC to get more information with what is going on and I noticed this:

`No.   | Time | Source          | Destination     | Protocol | Length | Info`

`1 | 327  | 192.168.2.108   | 224.0.0.251     | MDNS     | 83     | Standard query 0x0000 A Ryans-MacBook-Pro.local, "QU" question`

`2 | 328  | 192.168.2.108   | 224.0.0.251     | MDNS     | 83     | Standard query 0x0000 A Ryans-MacBook-Pro.local, "QM" question`

`3 | 331  | 192.168.2.108   | 224.0.0.251     | MDNS     | 83     | Standard query 0x0000 A Ryans-MacBook-Pro.local, "QM" question`

`4 | 332  | 192.168.2.108   | 192.168.2.5     | TCP      | 78     | 49860  >  389 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=32 TSval=371626102 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1`

`5 | 332  | 192.168.2.5     | 192.168.2.108   | TCP      | 74     | 389  >  49860 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2494847497 TSecr=371626102`

`6 | 332  | 192.168.2.108   | 192.168.2.5     | TCP      | 66     | 49860  >  389 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=131744 Len=0 TSval=371626102 TSecr=2494847497`

`7 | 332  | 192.168.2.108   | 192.168.2.5     | LDAP     | 96     | bindRequest(1) "ldap" simple`

`8 | 332  | 192.168.2.5     | 192.168.2.108   | LDAP     | 88     | bindResponse(1) success`

As you can see, when I initiate the `ldap_connect()` function, I immediate see the first packet at 327 seconds (since running Wireshark). I see 3 mdns packets for a total of 5 seconds. Then on the fourth, fifth and sixth packets I see the TCP three-way handshake and then it continues to give me a successful ldap connection. Therefore the 5 second delay I'm seeing is all mdns packets or Apple's Bonjour? At this point, I have no idea how to fix this.

Disclaimer: I am using [Laravel Valet](https://github.com/laravel/valet) which uses dnsmasq. I have no idea if this is causing my issue or not. I have not uninstalled this software yet to find out.

**edit:** I've ruled out Laravel Valet. I completely uninstalled it and it's still an issue. I've also ruled out Laravel. I'm running this script and the issue still exists:

```
<?php

$start = microtime(true);

$ldap = ldap_connect('ldap://192.168.2.5:389');

$end = microtime(true);

echo $end - $start;
```

**edit2:** Ok I've gotten further with solving this. I installed Wireshark on my Mac and noticed the below as well.

[image]

Then I ran this command:
`➜  ~ scutil --dns`
    DNS configuration

```
resolver #1
  search domain[0] : corp.[redacted].com
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.2.4
  nameserver[1] : 192.168.2.5
  if_index : 7 (en3)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Reachable, Directly Reachable Address

resolver #2
  domain   : local
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Not Reachable
  order    : 300000
```

It's my hostname! My hostname is causing a 5 second delay trying to resolve it using multicast DNS. Why? `.local` is a reserved domain so why would Apple append it to my hostname?

[image]

As you can see, it automatically appends `.local`.

Anyway, I've resolved my issue by adding `127.0.0.1    Ryans-MacBook-Pro.local` to my `/etc/hosts` file. For some reason it wasn't in there.

My `ldap_connect()` is now instant like it should be!

Comment: I also get that 5 secs when resolving from `/etc/hosts` ... seems like an mDNSresponder issue .

Comment: Since I'm using the ip address of the server and not the hostname or FQDN, I have no idea why it would even try to resolve out of /etc/hosts or even DNS for that matter?

Comment: after investigating, it seems that i get the 5 seconds when coming from a php process (cli and via sapi) ... and not in shell.  More investigation in progress.

Comment: this solves it for me , but not certain how it relates to ldap : `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);` , apparently some weird issue with ipv6. If you have access to php.ini, try to add this via `curl` options.

Comment: I don't see any options like that for `ldap_connect()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-set-option.php

Comment: i was suggesting `php.ini` , default curl options (possibly in conf.d/ext-curl.ini on a mac., because under the hood php's `ldap_connect` could rely on php's `curl`.

Comment: See my edit2. I seem to have fixed this. Can you tell me what your `/etc/hosts` file looks like?

Comment: the most interesting part is that ldap_connect does *not* connect to the server. Internaly it calls ldap_initialize which creates an LDAP resource but does not open a network connection. The connection will be established as soon as a network connection is necessary (usually on ldap_bind) - That does *not* refer to f.e. DNS queries or stuff like that...

Comment: It must be? It's initiating a 3 way TCP handshake?

Comment: How did you get PHP installed on your MAC?

Comment: https://brew.sh/ then `brew install php71`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your hostname is in the `/etc/hosts` file like this:

`127.0.0.1    localhost    Ryans-MacBook-Pro.local`

Just replace my hostname with yours.